# Google Deployment Manager error when using manual IP allocation in NAT (HTTP 400)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

## Context

I am trying to associate serverless egress with a static IP address ([GCP Docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip)). I have been able to set this up manually through the gcp-console, and now I am trying to implement it with deployment manager. However, with just the IP address and the router, once I add the NAT config, I get 400's, "Request contains an invalid argument.", which is not giving me enough information to fix the problem.

```yaml
# config.yaml
resources:
# addresses spec: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses
  - name: serverless-egress-address
    type: compute.v1.address
    properties:
      region: europe-west3
      addressType: EXTERNAL
      networkTier: PREMIUM

  # router spec: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/routers
  - name: serverless-egress-router
    type: compute.v1.router
    properties:
      network: projects/<project-id>/global/networks/default
      region: europe-west3
      nats:
        - name: serverless-egress-nat
          natIpAllocateOption: MANUAL_ONLY
          sourceSubnetworkIpRangesToNat: ALL_SUBNETWORKS_ALL_IP_RANGES
          natIPs:
          - $(ref.serverless-egress-address.selfLink)
```

```
# error response
code: RESOURCE_ERROR
location: /deployments/<deployment-name>/resources/serverless-egress-router
message: '{
  "ResourceType":"compute.v1.router",
  "ResourceErrorCode":"400",
  "ResourceErrorMessage":{
    "code":400,
    "message":"Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/<project-id>/regions/europe-west3/routers/serverless-egress-router",
    "httpMethod":"PUT"
}}'
```

Notably, if I remove the 'natIPs' array and set 'natIpAllocateOption' to 'AUTO_ONLY', it goes through without errors. While this is not the configuration I need, it does narrow the problem down to these config options.

## Question

- Which is the invalid argument?
- Are there things outside of the YAML which I should check? In the docs it says the following, which makes me wonder if there are other caveats like it:

> Note that if this field contains ALL_SUBNETWORKS_ALL_IP_RANGES or ALL_SUBNETWORKS_ALL_PRIMARY_IP_RANGES, then there should not be any other Router.Nat section in any Router for this network in this region.

Comment: According to the API docs your options should be correct. I think it might have to do with the self-reference output. Have you tried passing the resource URI of the address instead of the reference? `https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my-project/regions/the-region1/addresses`

Comment: Yes, I tried the URL which i get via CLI: 'gcloud compute addresses describe serverless-egress-address'

Answer (score 1):

I checked the [API reference](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/routers/insert) and passing the values that you used should work. Furthermore, if you talk directly to the API using a JSON payload with these, it return 200:

```
{
  "name": "nat",
  "network": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/global/networks/nat1",
  "nats": [
    {
      "natIps": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/regions/us-central1/addresses/test"
      ],
      "name": "nat1",
      "natIpAllocateOption": "MANUAL_ONLY",
      "sourceSubnetworkIpRangesToNat": "ALL_SUBNETWORKS_ALL_IP_RANGES"
    }
  ]
}
```

From what I can see the request is correctly formed using methods other than Deployment Manager so there might be an issue in the tool.

I have [filed an issue about this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/160459859) on Google's Issue Tracker for them to take a look at it.

The DM team might be able to shed light on what's happening here.

Comment: Thank you! Does this mean you were able to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, using the same reference as you and even passing the self link.